# CNN para clasificar proteínas

Tags: python, redes-neuronales, pytorch

Estoy construyendo mi primer CNN pero tengo serios problemas con mi *accuracy*. La idea es clasificar proteínas; tengo una base de datos con los id y las secuencias. ejemplo a continuación.

```
seq1    MQICGLVKTAKTPSCWSTVPYGREVGSPMTHQQHETERLQYKRWSGCNGFHGGKIRQYLFNMQGTDCKTDQTAGMAISESFLDFQGDHSYEELNAHPIFQTWPPNNSIRDDCL
seq2    MTGVKGTYGTPNVFQSTNEVSSGDQKIPWPKTEQTACLWGLPLSQFPIRKVIREIDNANTAIINLSLQDPNGNCNCMSKDSYTWWFRYARFHRCGRCIWMPWNGDRCDKYEKYYTDNMLYPEPNQLDSDRIKRGACHSDGMTDHGRDNGKWCCFVINLDDPSHTLP
seq3    MCHYAWCMWNTGCHWGINEEWAFHDKDLQGFPRKLHRPTRPKHYDTCLDDFSMCSTMCEARNVQRYNNWDRVRNRSQNVFDSYQDISRRAHFDSRQDDVLTDTKCYTNEFCHCELSPDMLFLGRTPNTSQAKPHIHVITRPNCNCHPRNQWATMIYYQWKLRQESETVIDQNKGCFSIFAKKEAGTWGIEFTLLYAK
seq4    MQVLNSMLDKVTQDWGKKCGLVKTAKTPQFWILVRRNPSVPVAAAMSINCFSTPRHELYKVRMMGWGSLYKNRQTYNSLSTLMRHSSMPSGVTDCVYWAVFGESIDDDWAWWLRADNDFLWFGNDTDRSIGLYINSCSRVDWMWANHFSE
```

Otra base de datos con los labels (1,0), uno las bases de datos por el id, obtengo los correspondientes *train* and *test*. y luego escribo mi humilde modelo.

```
class Conv1DProteinClassifier(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, embed_size, num_filters,kernel_sizes,
               num_classes):
      super(Conv1DProteinClassifier, self).__init__()
      self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embed_size)
      self.conv_layers=nn.ModuleList([
          nn.Conv1d(in_channels=embed_size,
                    out_channels=num_filters,
                    kernel_size=fs)
          for fs in kernel_sizes
      ])
      self.pool =  nn.AdaptiveAvgPool1d(1)
      self.output_layer = nn.Linear(num_filters*len(kernel_sizes),num_classes) 
      #self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)

  def forward(self, inputs):
      embeddings = self.embedding(inputs).permute(0, 2, 1)
      #print("Tamaño de embeddings:", embeddings.size())
      conv_outputs=[]
      for conv in self.conv_layers:
          conv_outputs.append(torch.relu(conv(embeddings)))
          #print("Tamaño de salida de la capa convolucional:", conv_outputs[-1].size())
      pooled_outputs=[]
      for conv_outputs in conv_outputs:
          pooled=self.pool(conv_outputs)
          pooled_outputs.append(pooled.squeeze(-1))
      encoding = torch.cat(pooled_outputs,dim=1)
      #encoding=self.dropout(encoding)
      logits = self.output_layer(encoding).squeeze(-1)
      return logits
```

Luego, por supuesto, la función train:

```
def train_and_plot(net, train_iter, test_iter, trainer, num_epochs, loss_fn):
    train_loss, train_acc, n = [], [], 0
    
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        epoch_loss, epoch_acc = 0.0, 0.0
        
        for X, y in train_iter:
            trainer.zero_grad()
            y_hat = net(X)
            loss = loss_fn(torch.softmax(y_hat, dim=0), y.float())
            loss.backward()
            trainer.step()
            
            epoch_loss += loss.item()
            epoch_acc += (y_hat.argmax(dim=-1) == y).sum().item()
            n += y.shape[0]
        
        train_loss.append(epoch_loss / n)
        train_acc.append(epoch_acc / n)
        #print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}: train loss {train_loss[-1]:.4f}, train acc {train_acc[-1]:.4f}")
    
    # Plotting
    epochs = list(range(1, num_epochs+1))
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    color = 'tab:red'
    ax1.set_xlabel('Epochs')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Training Loss', color=color)
    ax1.plot(epochs, train_loss, color=color)
    ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

    ax2 = ax1.twinx()

    color = 'tab:blue'
    ax2.set_ylabel('Training Accuracy', color=color)
    ax2.plot(epochs, train_acc, color=color)
    ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

La cual corro con los siguientes parámetros:

```
vocab_size, embed_size, num_filters,kernel_sizes,num_classes=21,20,64,[3,6,10],1
net=Conv1DProteinClassifier(vocab_size, embed_size, num_filters,kernel_sizes,num_classes)
lr, num_epochs = 0.01,500
trainer=optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=lr)
loss = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
trainer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=lr)
train_and_plot(net,train_iter,test_iter,trainer, num_epochs=num_epochs, loss_fn=loss)
```

Todo funciona pero my *accuracy* es de 0 :'( aunque el *training loss* también es bajo. Es mi primer modelo y de acuerdo a las indicaciones debo usar CNN con Conv1D. No sé si el modelo que estoy planteando simplemente no sirve para lo que necesito. Traté de escribir otro usando *OneHot enconding* pero no lo logré.

La pregunta es: ¿el modelo que estoy proponiendo tiene futuro? ¿cómo puedo mejorar el accuracy?